# Problem adding 'has-children' class to wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus, wpdb, sub-menu

According to a number of references online, I should be able to use the following function to add the class, `has-children`, to menu items that have children under them:

```
function gtp_nav_menu_css_class( $css_class, $item ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $has_children = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT COUNT(meta_id) FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key='_menu_item_menu_item_parent' AND meta_value='" . $item->ID . "'");
    if ($has_children > 0) {
        array_push($css_class, 'has-children');
    }
    return $css_class;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_css_class', 'gtp_nav_menu_css_class', 10, 4 );
```

I am using `wp_nav_menu()` in my `header.php`. However, after adding this code to `functions.php`, I am not seeing the `has-children` class being added to any menu items (when in fact there are menu items that contain children). Does anybody know what may be the culprit?

Notes:

- I am using WP 3.4.1.
- I am running a Multisite setup
- Table prefix is 'wp_'
- Via debug echo statements, I can see that the function is getting executed, but not inside the conditional statement.

Comment: what's your table prefix?

Comment: `$table_prefix  = 'wp_';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You <strike>can't</strike> shouldn't hardcode table names into queries, especially with multisite. Swap `$wpdb->postmeta` for `wp_postmeta` and it'll likely work.

edit- technically you *can*, edited for clarity.